# MSAL with UWP authenticating against Azure AD - certificate required?

Tags: azure, authentication, uwp, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

When using the MSAL library to authentication against Azure Active Directory from a UWP app, is there anything special that must be done with certificates to make it work?  ie, does the certificate required to run the UWP app have to be registered or "known" somehow by the Azure AD App Registration?

I would appreciate any references to online resources that delve more into this topic if the answer is 'yes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes!**

For mobile platforms such as UWP, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android, they only support public client applications. The public client application does not know how to prove the identity of the application to the identity provider.
A secure connection can only be achieved on the web application or Web API backend by deploying a certificate.

please see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2/uwp-signing-in-graph-aad/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#integrated-windows-authentication